# Calling different functions on a single button js

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

I have form with one button and I have two functions `foo1()` and `foo2`. if user clicks this button FIRST TIME, `onclick` event should call `foo1()`, in all other cases it should call `foo2`. How can I do this in js/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for the first click and inside that handler initialize a new event listener that would be used for subsequent events

```
$('button').one('click',function(){
    foo1();
    $(this).on('click', foo2);    
});
```

Comment: When you provide an answer to a poor question, you just enable more poor questions.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this :

```
$('button').on('click,foo);
function foo(){
  foo1();
  $(this).off("click",foo).on('click', foo2);
}
```

Comment: When you provide an answer to a poor question, you just enable more poor questions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var initClick;
var initClick = false;

$(".button").click(function(){
 if(initClick == false){
    foo();
    initClick = true;
 }else{
   bar();
 }
});


function foo(){
 alert('Foo');
}

function bar(){
 alert('Bar');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" >Click Me</button>
```

Comment: When you provide an answer to a poor question, you just enable more poor questions.